# How to remove some address components from google autocomplete results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using google autocomplete service in my web application for address suggestions. Can any one suggest how to remove some address components like `country, pincode` from autocomplete service returned results. Following is my code,

```
function locationAutocomplete() {

      $('.locationTxt,#locationFind').focus(function(){

           var options = {
                types: ['geocode'],                
                componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'in'
             }
           }; 

            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this,options);            

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                var thisplace = autocomplete.getPlace();                  

            });
      });
}
```

If I'm not wrong, I think all returned results will have `latitude` and `longitude` information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API-based option to access/modify the printed suggestions.

What you can do: create your own autocomplete  and populate it with data.

Request the  predictions via the [autocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) .
The details (e.g. geometry) may be request via a further request: [PlacesService.getDetails()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests)